# How can I reload page in fetch request

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I want to find a solution that reload my page, after my deleting request.
**The problem is after reloading I can't set value** like: `projectBox.style.display = "block";`

Because the browser execute reloading function at the end, so I can't set a new value to display project filed, it redirect me to my default setting which are `ContactBox.style.display = "block";`

I already try reloading with : `window.location.href = window.location.href;` and `history.go(0);`

And I also tried to add another `.then()` but it doesn't change anything it first changes the value and then it reloads.

[image]

```
 deleteProjectButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Empêche le comportement par défaut du formulaire
      let formData = new FormData(
        document.getElementById("delete-company-project-form")
      );

      fetch("/delete-company-project", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(),
      })
        .then(() => {
          // Hide the contact box and show the project box
          window.location.href = window.location.href;
          contactBox.style.display = "none";
          projectBox.style.display = "block";
          opportunitiesBox.style.display = "none";
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle error
          console.error(
            "There has been a problem with your fetch operation:",
            error
          );
        });
    });
```

Comment: post CODE, not pretty pictures of CODE

Answer (score 0):

This function will reload the page. but please place it the loaction where it does not recursively load an application.
window.location.reload();

Comment: Can you give more information ? To resolve

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteProjectButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Empêche le comportement par défaut du formulaire
      let formData = new FormData(
        document.getElementById("delete-company-project-form")
      );

      fetch("/delete-company-project", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(),
      })
        .then(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle error
          console.error(
            "There has been a problem with your fetch operation:",
            error
          );
        });
    });
```

Hide the contact box and show the project box

```
          contactBox.style.display = "none";
          projectBox.style.display = "block";
          opportunitiesBox.style.display = "none";
```

place this code in onLoad function

Comment: you should append this to your previous answer

Comment: or just delete the other idk

Comment: it's good idea but when I tried it doesn't work it not execute : my     function updateUI() {
      contactBox.style.display = "none";
      projectBox.style.display = "block";
      opportunitiesBox.style.display = "none";
      console.log("It doesn't log in browser ..");
    }